# Can I use double prepositions in the beginning and in the end of a sentence?

Tags: prepositions

Is it legally correct to put prepositions in the beginning and the end of a sentence? This question appeared when I was doing an exercise about prepositions in questions.

Here's the problem, by the way:

> **Write questions for these answers, using 'Who' or 'What'.**
>
> "I'll carry it in a paper bag."

The key answer is

> What will you carry it in?

I'm asking if it's legal and correct to add a preposition *with* before *what*:

> With what will you carry it in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because in:

> With what will you carry it in?

"In" and "With" are serving the same function. To have both would be essentially duplicating a word--you might as well be asking (also incorrect):

> In what will you carry it in?

So any of these are fine (in increasing order of formality):

- What will you carry it in?
- What will you carry it with?
- In what will you carry it?
- With what will you carry it?

But you don't need both "in" and "with."